# Error about i686 packages not found when installing with yum? (on x64 architecture)

Tags: yum

I get these errors when running yum install ... (for pretty much any package)

The 'examplerepo' refers to my repository in `/etc/yum.repos.d` that I configured to point to 
`baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/`

```
Error: Package: tigervnc-server-minimal-1.3.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@ftp3)
           Requires: libX11.so.6()(64bit)
           Removing: libX11-1.6.3-3.el7.x86_64 (@ftp3)
               libX11.so.6()(64bit)
           Updated By: libX11-1.6.4-3.el6.i686 (examplerepo)
               Not found
Error: Package: cairo-1.14.2-1.el7.x86_64 (@ftp3-updates)
           Requires: libxcb-shm.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: libxcb-1.11-4.el7.x86_64 (@ftp3-updates)
               libxcb-shm.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: libxcb-1.12-4.el6.i686 (examplerepo)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:totem-3.14.3-6.el7.x86_64 (@ftp3)
           Requires: libX11.so.6()(64bit)
           Removing: libX11-1.6.3-3.el7.x86_64 (@ftp3)
               libX11.so.6()(64bit)
           Updated By: libX11-1.6.4-3.el6.i686 (examplerepo)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: I get a 404 when I go to that page.. Usually I am presented with a list of packages, unless I am missing something. Try making this your baseurl then doing a `yum clean all` and `yum check-update`: http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/

Comment: Oops, looks like 7.3 doesn't have packages. I changed it to http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cutrightjm for the answer. I changed the url to something that actually works, then yum clean all + yum check-update fixed the problem.

Comment: »» I changed it to vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64 «« : That's an old version. And no updates. The basic baseurl is http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/ ... Updates is http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/ ... All 7.3 repo files https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTFhfdzJhdWpsdHc/view?usp=sharing .. EPEL, SCLo are included.